# Prove the congurence

Tags: divisibility

I am looking for a proof of Gauss's generalization of Wilson's Theorem.

> Let $S$ be the set of all the integers which are less than and mutually prime to $n (>4)$ (not of the form $p^\alpha$, $2p^\alpha$ for all odd $p$). Denote the elements of $S$ by $a_i$  $\forall i$ $\mid$ $1 \leq i \leq \phi(n)$ and $a_i<a_{i+1}$. Then show that,
>
> $$\prod_{i=1}^{\phi(n)} a_i \equiv 1 \quad (\text{mod} n)$$

I have searched in Wikipedia but there is only the reference of Gauss's *Arithmatica* which I am unable to find as an e-book.

Any hint to the proof will be appreciated.

Comment: Define an equivalence relation on $S$, $x\sim y \iff (x = y \lor xy \equiv 1 \pmod{n})$. Look at the singleton equivalence classes.

Comment: Such group-theoretic generalizations of Wilson's theorem have been [previously discussed](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+wilson%27s+group) here at length.